# Выравнивание по центру

Tags: css

Отверстал шаблон, стал натягивать на cms  получаю такую штуку. Выравнивание блоков на cms  почему то стало сверху, хотя стили у элементов одинаковые. Элементы строчные h3 например из Computed

```
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(113, 113, 113);
display: block;
font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
font-size: 21px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 60px;
line-height: 23.1px;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 20px;
width: 293.328px;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2):

```
line-height: 60px;
```

п.с. на самом деле будет лучше `59px`

Comment: Не помогает http://prntscr.com/8sx1ca

Comment: А вот отдельно свёрстано http://prntscr.com/8sx1u7